# Managing SharedPreferences in both PreferenceActivity and Service within same app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-service, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I'm building an app with a *PreferenceActivity* and a *Service* (running in its own remote process due to *android:process=":remote"* flag) and both need to access programmatically the *SharedPreferences*. At present time I'm getting a *SharedPreference* object with the following code that uses the *getSharedPreferences* method defined in both *Service* and *PreferenceActivity* classes:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("com.mypackage_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)
```

Is this the same as the following?

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()
```

**1)** In the second one I can not specify flags, or is there a way to specify them?

**2)** Do I really need to specify MODE_MULTI_PROCESS since I'm accessing/modifying the shared preferences from both *Service* and *PreferenceActivity*? I think that most of the time you have a *PreferenceActivity* that modifies the properties and another *Activity* that reads/modifies them, so is MODE_MULTI_PROCESS needed almost always or is it only needed when there are multiple and possibly concurrent accesses to the *SharedPreferences* (as in my case, with the background service that can be active while you're editing preferences in *PreferenceActivity*)

**3)** The documentation of [MODE_MULTI_PROCESS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS%20MODE_MULTI_PROCESS) says *This behavior is sometimes desired in cases where the application has multiple processes, all writing to the same SharedPreferences file*, does this mean that my *Service* and my *PreferenceActivity* can point different preference files? How do you change the preference file name in a *PreferenceActivity*?

**4)** Shared preferences are named in this way because they are shared among all the components (activities, services etc) of your application, right? Non shared preferences (i.e. the ones you can get with *getPreferences()* in you activity) are local to the component that creates them but are being saved in the same *com.mypackage_preferences* file? This could answer to my doubts in point **3)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` if you are accessing the preferences from different **processes**. If you just have different activities that are using the shared prefs then you don't need `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`.

You mention that you have a service. As long as the service is running in the same process as the activities you still don't need `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`. The service will run by default in the same process unless you have specified `android:process="..."` in the `<service>` tag in the manifest.

Comment: Will it run in the same process even if the activity is killed and restarted and the service is started at boot? I.e., does the system recognize the server and the activity belong to the same package and then runs them in the same process? This sounds quite strange to me, I thought they were not running in the same process because the activity does not start the service or maybe it can start it and then it can be killed, with the server still running in the background (it is a background service and I do not stop it unless the user wants it to be stopped).

Comment: can you briefly explain me how to set the android:process attribute to specify I want the Service to be run in a different process? If I do that, do I avoid the service being killed if the user kills the Activity that started it (i.e. through the task manager)? Furthermore, if the service is started by a broadcast receiver that intercepts a BOOT_COMPLETED event, does the service live in its own process and does it receive intents from Activities that later on call startService for that service?

Comment: If you don't explicitly set the `android:process` attribute in the `<service>` tag in the manifest then the service and activities will all run in the same process within the same virtual machine. That is the default behaviour. The OS will still individually control the service and activities and start and stop them as it normally does. If you want to have the service run in a separate process, then specify `android:process=":service"` in the `<service> tag in the manifest. This will cause the service to run in a separate process that is private to your application.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. Just to be sure I've understood well, if then the user kills the activity, only the activity's process will be killed, while the service one survives, right?

Comment: Users can't kill activities (at least not with the application manager). Users can kill applications using the application manager and in this case all your activities and your service will be killed (even if they are in separate processes)

Comment: So, if the service is started through the broadcast receiver at boot the user won't see it in the task manager until an activity within the same app is started and to kill it the user must look in the running apps list within settings..? Isn't there any way to avoid the user being able to kill the background service through the task manager? I think I will add a sort of visual notification for the user, to inform it that when it kills the app the service is stopped.. is there any callback to understand when the service is being closes due to a kill-app event?

Comment: If I've understood well, when the user kills the app within the task manager, the system simply kills the application processes and no callbacks are invoked... so, I could solve my problems by adding a warning in the Activity launched by the user to inform it that it should not kill the activity and then add a button to simply close (finish) the current activity.

Comment: what's the benefit of running the Service in another android process, if it is killed with the activities running in the same app but in another process?

Comment: I can see at least 2 benefits right away: 1) You can get around the per-process memory limits by splitting a large application into 2 processes (keeping the business logic and data in the service and just the UI-stuff in the activities process. 2) If one of the process crashes, the other one doesn't necessarily. This can be both a blessing and a curse, depending on how you program it. I think for general-use applications there isn't any benefit, which is why the default behaviour is to have everything in a single process.

Answer (score 0):

The other big advantage: garbage collects in a busy service don't interfere with animations in the user interface.