# Default Shared Preferences give me wrong values in Service

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a PreferenceFragment where I have defined a CheckBoxPreference in XML. I need to check this value in a Service, but it always gives me the old value. I noticed the value is correctly changed when I restart the application.

My Preference Fragment :

```
public class OptionsFragment extends PreferenceFragment 
{

    public static final String WIFI_ONLY = "wifi";

    private SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getInstance());

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.config);
    }

 }
```

My config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="wifi"
        android:summary="Check if you want to use wifi only"
        android:title="Use Wifi only" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

My Service :

```
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyApplication.getInstance());        
Log.d(TAG, "isWifiOnly : "+settings.getBoolean(OptionsFragment.WIFI_ONLY, true));
```

The log always return the same value no matter if I change it or not, except if i restart the app. Also, in my MainActivity I have that line in OnCreate():

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.config, false);
```

It creates the config file with the default value if needed.

I'm doing something wrong, the question is what ?

Comment: I think I also have this problem, and I solved it by using `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136677/not-getting-the-updated-value-of-the-shared-preference-in-the-service) is what I found before. Edit: too fast to comment, didn't read whole question; In this case, maybe `PreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesMode()` will do the trick.

Comment: setSharedPreferencesMode() is not static, i had to add this line in my preference fragment, right after addPreferencesFromResource() : getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);  But unfortunately it sill doesn't work

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the documentation carefully... and also, that time, I used local `SharedPreferences` in `Service` and it worked. Apologize if this doesn't really help.

Comment: It helps :) Can you please describe how did you write your local SharedPreferences in your Service ? Do you use the DefaultSharedPrerences with the ApplicationContext ? or do you use a simple SharedPreferences linked with a name and a mode ?

Comment: I used SharedPreferences linked with an Activity. Since I can't access the code now, I cannot describe it. (kind of forgot, but I believe I just use it like normal SharedPreferences). I'll get back to you if I have time.

Comment: Thanks for your time anyway. You pointed out something very interesting and I think the multi process access is the issue here

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to this link [Managing SharedPreferences in both PreferenceActivity and Service within same app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546511/managing-sharedpreferences-in-both-preferenceactivity-and-service-within-same-ap) and thanks to Andrew T. :

The issue was the multi process mode. If you have a Service which is declared in the manifest with a android:process="" (which is my case) then it's necessary to set a multi process mode.

Here is what i did :

in PreferenceFragment :

```
public static final String CONFIG_NAME = "pref";

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(CONFIG_NAME);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.config);

    ...
}
```

My Service :

```
SharedPreferences settings = MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferences(OptionsFragment.CONFIG_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

and I set the default values in MainActivity this way :

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), OptionsFragment.CONFIG_NAME, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS, R.xml.config, false);
```

And now it works fine. Hope it will help !

Thank you again Andrew T.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue for the last days...

I have a preference.xml with my layout and keys and inflate it into a PreferenceFragment while Listening on changes and thereby informing a Service of my Application of any change.
The crucial part is to set the mode of the SharedPreference access right:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
}
```

The `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` flag makes commits() apply to all accessing processes so even my Service would get direct access to the just changed values.

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key)
{
    if(SettingsManager.setupIsValid(getActivity())){
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), IntentService.class);
        startServiceIntent.setAction("PREFERENCES_CHANGED");
        getActivity().startService(startServiceIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.settings_incomplete), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This will first do check magic and whenever the settings are valid inform the service of the change.

This allows the usage of multiple processes and always current preference values across all processes.

P.S.: direct access then looks like this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```