# SharedPreferences empty after restarting service / device

Tags: firebase, service, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, firebase-cloud-messaging

As I am working with Google Firebase for Push Notifications, I want to save the *Instance Token* to the `SharedPreferences`. Unfortunately, whenever the token gets refreshed and want to check the previous one from `SharedPreferences`, they are empty...

Is it because I am using a `Service` here?

```
public class MyFirebaseIIDService : FirebaseInstanceIdService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        var sharedPreferencesEditor = sharedPreferences.Edit();

        // Get Firebase Instance Token
        var refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.Instance.Token;

        // Check if a Firebase Instance Token has been registered before and unregister it
        var oldToken = sharedPreferences.GetString("FirebaseInstanceToken", null);

        if (oldToken != null) // is ALWAYS null :(
        {
            // Unregister old token...
        }

        // Save the Firebase Instance Token locally
        sharedPreferencesEditor.PutString("FirebaseInstanceToken", refreshedToken);
        sharedPreferencesEditor.Apply();

        // At this point, the SharedPreferences have to token saved.
        // Next time, the app reaches this point, it is gone... 
    }
}
```

Sorry for the syntax confusion, I use Xamarin, so this is C# but it should not make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem and it turned out, that my code was working correctly but behaved strange on my test device.

After re-building the application, `SharedPreferences` have been cleared, although I checked the *Preserve application data/cache on device between deploys* option in Visual Studio. That was because my physical testing device was ***rooted*** and did not accept this option.

When trying on an unrooted device, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it work in xamarin but in native android getSharedPreferences from service context maybe wrong. You should use only applicationContext or MODE_MULTI_PROCESS when open shared preferences.

You can see similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674571/default-shared-preferences-give-me-wrong-values-in-service).

Xamarin and C# also have this mode when your open some file, so i think exactly the same with preferences. Try some like this instead of using GetDefaultSharedPreferences:

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences ("PREF_NAME", FileCreationMode.MultiProcess);
```

Comment: Xamarin ist a 1:1 C# to Java mapping, so everything that exists in Java-Android does also exist in Xamarin. Unfortunately, your proposed solution did not do the trick. Still null, after the app gets restarted...

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall your app to refresh you token? If yes I think you can not get the old token because the `SharedPreferences` is cleared when you uninstall your app.

I have tried java code to save the token :

```
public void onTokenRefresh() {
        // Get updated InstanceID token.

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d("Mike", "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

        SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("hello",0);
        String oldToken = mSharedPreferences.getString("Token",null);

        if(oldToken == null)
        {
            Log.d("Mike", "oldToken: " + null);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString("Token", refreshedToken);
        mEditor.commit();

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        //sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);

    }
```

At first time you install your app you will get the token and save it in the `SharedPreferences`, next time you open your app and show the old token in the textview then you can find your token has been saved , And do not uninstall your app:

```
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("hello",0);
    String oldToken = mSharedPreferences.getString("Token",null);
    tv1.setText(oldToken);
```

It works. But when you uninstall your app the `textview` shows null.[image]

Comment: Yes, I do uninstall and re-install the application to refresh the token but Visual Studio has an *Preserve application data/cahce on device between deploys* option, which I activated. BUT: I solved the problem. The physical device, I was testing on, was **rooted** and so this option does not work. Tried with an unrooted phone which worked fine.